# how can I find out if a method exist for a doctrine model in symfony?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have a doctrine model that has a method getSomethingId()

and I'm making something of an automated form generator for internal use in the company

how can I check if my model has this method?

I've tried with php's method_exists but it returns false for every method, what can I do?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try is_callable()

Comment: thanks for the recommendation I'll try it and vote tomorrow from work

Answer (score -1):

prueba asi

```
$class=get_class($object);
if ( method_exists($class , $method)||$object->getTable()->hasField($fieldName)) {
  $string= str_replace($matches,call_user_func(array($object, $method)),$string);
}
```